# Is it possible to create a ByteArray of ByteArrays as elements in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin

I have some issues with creating a `ByteArray` var where its elements are also `ByteArray`, I **don't know** is it *possible* first ? and how to ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried in terms of code or research, please be specific.

Comment: How about this: List<byte[]> listOfByteArrays = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of byte arrays perhaps? A byte array is meant to only hold bytes

Comment: sure I have a variable I called allByteArray:ByteArray 
and I want to put in each index of that variable one ByteArray 
I need Something like :
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
@TaseerAhmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ByteArray` is just what it sounds like, an array of bytes. If you want to hold onto multiple byte arrays you can use a generic list or array.

Something like this:

```
// say you have three byte arrays
val ba1 = ByteArray(3) { it.toByte() }
val ba2 = ByteArray(3) { (it + 3).toByte() }
val ba3 = ByteArray(3) { (it + 6).toByte() }

// make a list of them like so
val allByteArray = listOf(ba1, ba2, ba3)
```

Based on your more recent comment it seems you may want to add to allByteArray in a loop, if that is the case you can also use an `ArrayList` like this:

```
val allByteArray = ArrayList<ByteArray>()
for (i in 0 until 3) {
    // some byte array
    val ba = ByteArray(3) { (it + (i*3)).toByte() }

    // add to list
    allByteArray.add(ba)
}
```

Also as suggested by Alexey Romanov, you could do this in the constructor for a `MutableList` (or the same thing can be done with a list if it doesn't need to be mutable) like this:

```
val allByteArray = MutableList(3) { i ->
    ByteArray(3) { (it + (i*3)).toByte() }
}
```

Comment: In a loop for the new ByteArray will delete the oldest one isn't that true ?

Comment: @RIKI not entirely sure what you're asking, are you trying to append a bunch of byte arrays to a list within a for loop?

Comment: @RIKI if this answer help to resolve your issue then you should upvote and mark as answer like [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: I tried to but this popUp is shown 
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
Sorry but it's site policy here

Comment: That last should better use `MutableList(3) { i -> ... }` constructor.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You're right that would also work, but OP seemed to imply he wanted it in a for loop so I gave him a way to do it with one so thats why i used the arraylist like i had, perhaps ill add your solution as another option

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for a 2D array of Bytes? You can create an Array of ByteArrays:

```
val array = Array(3){ByteArray(3)}
array[0][1] = 3 // for example
```

or to initialize it as you declare it:

```
val array = arrayOf(
    byteArrayOf(0, 1, 2),
    byteArrayOf(3, 4, 5),
    byteArrayOf(6, 7, 0)
)
```

In Java this would be:

```
byte[][] array = new byte[3][3];
// or
byte[][] array = {
    {0, 1, 2},
    {3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 0},
}
```